# Is aggregate initialization with a new struct valid?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, initialization, aggregate

Would a phrase such as `Struct* a = new Struct{1,2,3};` be valid?

It compiles and runs just fine, but I'm wondering if there's anything funky going on behind the scenes.

```
struct Struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
}
```

Comment: Please post the definition of the `struct`

Comment: Depends on what `Struct` is.

Comment: What funky things do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

That code will allocate memory for a new `Struct` and initialize the members with 1, 2 and 3, and finally put the pointer to that structure into the variable `a`. I have no idea whether you call that funky, though.